What are the consequences of breaking a lease and leaving the country as non-citizen in Ohio
I have a lease until the end of September 2024 in Ohio. I’m a non-citizen who is going back to his home country in the beginning of May. I might have a cancer and I don’t have an insurance in the U.S so I don’t have any other option than going back to my home country. I already gave one mont rent as security deposit and I’m willing to pay May and June rent but my landlord says I’m responsible to pay for all the rest of the months. I gave them a 30 day notice and I’m not planning to come back to the U.S, will they sue me just because I don’t pay July and August rent?

I’m voting to close this question because it is a legal question that requires a lawyer. But.... Why do you care? What if the landlord does sue you - so what? You know your home country laws better than us, probably, you can estimate what would happen with that lawsuit. My guess - it would be tossed out fairly quickly.
